# Sending an email from contact us form using only Angularjs and Send grid without back end API in place

Tags: angularjs, sendgrid

I have taken a look around the internet and all the solutions emphasize using Express and Node Js API in place to able to send an email. I would love to see any suggestions on how to best go about it because I don't have a backend in place. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need some sort of backend otherwise the API-Key will be exposed.
From the SendGrid documentation:

> When you have a browser-only application that reaches out to APIs, the API key has to be embedded in the application. Anyone with access to a browser-only application can access all of the Javascript source code, including your API keys.
>
> Making your API key publicly accessible could result in anyone authenticating API calls with your API key — this is a significant security concern both for you and SendGrid.

You could use a serverless AWS lambda function or google function which would be a "backend" but without having to support the infrastructure / use a big framework.